# What is a proper way of end-to-end (e2e) testing in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, selenium, vue.js, acceptance-testing, e2e-testing

Of cause I can use [selenium-standalone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone) with xpath to test an app. But testing SPA could be challenging sometime.

But, for example **angularjs's** team provides [protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) for this purpose.

The reason behind protractor as I can see is that protractor waits till angularjs will be loaded and few more features:

> Protractor provides some new locator strategies and functions which
>   are very helpful to automate the AngularJS application. Examples
>   include things like: waitForAngular, By.binding, By.repeater,
>   By.textarea, By.model, WebElement.all, WebElement.evaluate, etc.

**So, the question is**: Is it any tool or best practice for e2e testing in Vuejs?

**UPD:** feel free to post links to tutorials, example and everything cool about e2e-testing in vue.js. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the examples from Evan You, the creator of Vue. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli There are also links to a few sample applications that include testing such as https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The tool you are thinking about is [Nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/).
With this, you can do E2E testing with Vue.js.

Even better, this is bundled by default when you are using `vue-cli`, ready to run.

The command line to create a project with Nightwatch activated by default is `vue init webpack myProjectName`.

Here are [small](https://github.com/DevMountain/broken-site) [tutorials](https://dotdev.co/acceptance-testing-a-laravel-and-vue-js-application-4160b8e96156#.x8iey01h5) about it.

EDIT: Lately I used [Webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io/) a lot, and I must say I prefer it to Nightwatch (better documentation, reactive community with a live gitter, issues that are treated in a timely fashion, etc.)

Answer (score 17):

I recommend to use https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe.

Pros:

- easy install
- complete test harness
- javascript ES2016 with (async/await)
- flexible selector system
- smart assertions with retry policy
- reports

See the simple tutorial [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/getting-started/)

Answer (score 8):

I recommend [Cypress](https://cypress.io).

- single NPM dependency
- video recording right out of the box
- GUI that shows every step of the test.

Our docs are great: https://on.cypress.io/intro

For Vue specifically see this tutorial: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/01/29/vue-js-e2e-test-hacker-news/ and if you want to do unit testing of Vue components https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-vue-unit-test

Happy testing.

Comment: But Cypress only supports Chrome based browsers right?

Comment: It would be nice to have a minimalist working example repo. this is the third e2e i'm trying out today, almost running out of patience...

Comment: for now Cypress supports Chrome based browsers, Firefox support is close though

Comment: Minimalist working examples are everywhere for Cypress: https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes.html# https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/applications.html

Comment: Did you just recommended yourself? In the Netherlands we have a saying for this: "Wij van WC-eend adviseren WC-eend"

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be an old question, but at the end of 2019 the best way is *webdriverio*:

**Pros**:

1. Large ecosystem of plugins and integrations.
2. Mocha, cucumber, jasmine runners.
3. Sync mode of test runner.
4. Allure reporter and others out of the box.
5. Chromedriver service from the box.
6. Easy integrate with selenoid and get cluster of browsers in docker for parallel test execution.
7. Integration with devtools protocol and puppeteer, can use huge amount of functions.
8. Integration with cloud service providers.
9. Appium integration out of the box.

**Cons**:

1. Have to manually write waits.
2. Some functions require to use promises.